# WinForms Telerik RadGridView, как добавлять данные с помощью GridViewDataRowInfo

Tags: c#

При добавлении данных с помощью GridViewDataRowInfo в цикле, добавляется только последняя запись в чём может быть проблема?

```
for (int i = 0; i < listItems.Count; i++)
            {
                rowInfo.Cells["columnProductName"].Value = listItems[i].ProductName;
                rowInfo.Cells["columnUnitName"].Value = listItems[i].UnitName;
                rowInfo.Cells["columnStartYearCount"].Value = listItems[i].StartYearCount;
                rowInfo.Cells["columnAuthIncome"].Value = listItems[i].AuthIncome;

                radGridViewRequestReport.Rows.Add(rowInfo);
            }
```

Comment: последняя относительно `i` ?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц да.

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, Только сейчас перепроверил, выводиться вторая запись из трёх, относительно i.

Comment: та в добавление все норм...может дело в отрисовке ?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц вот об этом не подумал, буду проверять.